# Previously upvoted question now has 2 answers and logs me out when viewing

Tags: bug, status-completed, browser-cache

Over on SO, I upvoted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597363/asp-net-mvc-should-a-view-model-encapsulate-domain-model) about two hours ago.

But now, whenever I view it, I am logged out.

Comment: Can we please have some more information?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, because I had something similar happen on Meta the other day. It looked like a really weird caching issue (browser-side, server-side, or both). I solved it by doing a hard-refresh everytime a page looked not-up-to-date; this always retrieved the correct page. The problem was gone after a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok sorry all, seems like this must be some sort of strange caching issue. Must be at the ISP (I had tried flushing my browser cache), as viewing the question from home works fine (I was having the issue from work)... i.e. I am not logged out when viewing the said question.

I will try again at work tomorrow and post results...still seems pretty strange though because the last time before the issue occurred I hit the page was to upvote the question so I was obviously logged in.